# Getting Random Pop-up message in firefox browser only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting random pop-up message in Mozila Forefox browser, while clicking on links my application using .Net Framework MVC:

[image]

Only in chrome its fine. Please help me in this.

Comment: We need more information mate, you can try re-installing your Firefox as it seems something is wrong with your Firefox.

Comment: Thank you for reply just i re-install firefox but still same error i am getting -MRP

Comment: it was from my code now it is fixed